# Unable to clear form fields after Submit in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I am new to angular. I have looked up a lot of answers on clearing form fields after submitting but none seems to work. 
Here's my HTML code:

```
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="formSubmit()" class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">

       <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.FullName" placeholder="Full Name" required=""/>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.Address" placeholder="Address" required=""/>
         </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: purple;">Submit</button>

 </form>
```

Here's my JS code:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']); 
 myApp.controller("RegisterCtrl", function ($window,$scope,$http) {
   $scope.user={}
   $scope.formSubmit=function(){
     $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'myurl',
        data:$scope.user,
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    }).then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
             $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); 
             $scope.myForm.$setPristine(true); 
             $scope.myForm='';      


      })
     }
  });
```

I have tried setPristine as well as setUntouched but none working.

Comment: This question is tagged incorrectly. This forum is for angular 2+. Please change the tag to angularjs

Comment: @RRForUI this isn't a forum, and you can suggest edits to change the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see something strange in your code, i make plnkr based on your code, the modifications i do are below. also put the plnkr [sample](https://embed.plnkr.co/ZNY7Txhh37zsM2bPbApJ/)

**CONTROLLER**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']); 
 myApp.controller("RegisterCtrl", function ($window,$scope,$http) {
   $scope.user={}
   $scope.formSubmit=function(){
     $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'myurl',
        data:$scope.user,
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    }).then(function(res){
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.user = {};
      }, function(rej){ //error});
 }
 });
```

Comment: may be not work yours because isnt enter in the succes state of the promise, try to put `$scope.myForm.$setPristine();`also in the rejec like my plnkr does.

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']); 
 myApp.controller("RegisterCtrl", function ($window,$scope,$http) {
   $scope.user={}
   $scope.formSubmit=function(){
     $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'myurl',
        data:$scope.user,
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    }).then(function(res){
        $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-reset');
        $scope.forms.user = {};
        $scope.forms.userFrom.$setPristine = true;
      }, function(rej){ //error});
 }
 });
```